# Why can't I create a topic in Kafka?

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Following the [Apache Kafka Quickstart Guide](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/), I've done the following steps:

- Download and untar `kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz`
- `cd kafka_2.11-2.1.0`
- `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`
- In another terminal the the same dir, `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`
- `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`. Running `echo $?` afterward shows that this command exited with status `0`

Now the moment of truth. The guide says:

> We can now see that topic if we run the list topic command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
> test
```

However, I get no output from that command, and a piece of software I'm testing, which tries to send a message on the `"test"` topic, crashes because it finds 0 partitions for the topic.

I also have a Ruby program that sends messages to Kafka on topic `"test"`. It fails and retries, and I see the topic created at that point in the Kafka logs and can send messages to it. But even then, the command to list topics returns nothing.

Why can't I create a topic explicitly? Why can't I list topics that were created on demand? How can I troubleshoot this?

---

### Logs

Here's what I see in the logs: https://gist.github.com/nathanl/bea7a45a056b2d44146947ec88c29185

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.14

Comment: Are there any information in the logs, ex. errors, warnings?

Comment: @wardziniak There are some `INFO` messages from zookeeper that look like warnings; see my comments on Robin's answer.

Comment: fwiw, `brew install kafka` is maybe a "better" way to install it

Comment: If we're going "better" ways then Docker is also a great option :) e.g. https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.0-post/examples/kafka-single-node/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 11):

I faced to the same issue. However, I found out that the content of the script bin/kafka-topics.sh is empty somehow after the untar command.

So, I downloaded again the kafka, untar and check the content of the script file until I see it there, then it works.

Comment: Same here with 0 bytes on the topic file. Manually unzip and now it works!

Comment: You saved my day. I had same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.

First check if the `bin/kafka-topics.sh` has any content in it.

Then go ahead and clear all the tmp data of zookeeper and kafka

`rm -r /tmp/zookeeper`

`rm -r /tmp/kafka-log`

Then start your zookeeper and kafka again.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac 10.13.6, I followed the same steps, here are some troubleshooting steps for you to check.

When you start Zookeeper you should see in the stdout:

```
INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

When you start Kafka you should see in the stdout:

```
INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[…]
INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Started processors for 1 acceptors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
INFO Kafka version : 2.1.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
INFO Kafka commitId : 809be928f1ae004e (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

The `kafka-topics` command should return output (you don't mention any, which could be a sign something didn't work at this stage):

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
Created topic "test".
$
```

When you do this, in the Kafka stdout you'll see `Created log for partition test-0` amongst the log info:

```
INFO [Log partition=test-0, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
INFO [Log partition=test-0, dir=/tmp/kafka-logs] Completed load of log with 1 segments, log start offset 0 and log end offset 0 in 52 ms (kafka.log.Log)
INFO Created log for partition test-0 in /tmp/kafka-logs with properties {compression.type -> producer, message.format.version -> 2.1-IV2, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, min.compaction.lag.ms -> 0, message.timestamp.type -> CreateTime, message.downconversion.enable -> true, min.insync.replicas -> 1, segment.jitter.ms -> 0, preallocate -> false, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, unclean.leader.election.enable -> false, retention.bytes -> -1, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, cleanup.policy -> [delete], flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.ms -> 604800000, segment.bytes -> 1073741824, retention.ms -> 604800000, message.timestamp.difference.max.ms -> 9223372036854775807, segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
INFO [Partition test-0 broker=0] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition test-0 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
INFO Replica loaded for partition test-0 with initial high watermark 0 (kafka.cluster.Replica)
INFO [Partition test-0 broker=0] test-0 starts at Leader Epoch 0 from offset 0. Previous Leader Epoch was: -1 (kafka.cluster.Partition)
```

Topic then shows in the list:

```
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
test
```

Comment: When starting ZooKeeer and Kafka, I do see the messages you show. When Kafka starts, ZooKeeper outputs this and various similar messages: `[2019-02-07 11:53:03,156] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000e9a35560000 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0x20 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)`. It also outputs one with `Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/reassign_partitions` and the same for `/admin/preferred_replica_election`.

Comment: When I run the command to create a topic, nothing happens in the Kafka logs, no output is given, and none are listed afterward.

Comment: I have a Ruby program that sends messages to Kafka on topic "test". It fails and retries, and I see the topic created at that point in the Kafka logs and can send messages to it. But even then, the command to list topics returns nothing.

Comment: Are you running this all locally, bare metal, no funny networking, Docker, etc?

Comment: I don't see any `Error:KeeperErrorCode` in my ZooKeeper log, so that could be something to home in on. Assuming this is a a clean environment, I'd suggest (1) shutdown ZK (2) Shutdown Kafka (3) `rm -rf /tmp/zookeeper /tmp/kafka-log` (4) repeat your test, and update your question with full Zookeeper logs if you still see those errors

Comment: Thanks for your help, by the way. :) I've been `rm -rf`ing the logs as you show and and always have the same result. I had this problem previously with `kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz`, so I installed from `kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz` today, but no change.

Comment: Yeah, running locally, no Docker, nothing weird that I know of. I just followed the directions in the guide.

Comment: Please update the question with the ZK logs and we can take a deeper look

Comment: Posted a link to the logs (they would make the question gigantic if pasted here)

Comment: Do you let Zookeeper come up fully before starting Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue on a mac while running on a VPN, which somehow caused my hostname resolution to fail.

I solved this by editing `server.properties`, adding the line:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

1- first go to the `Kafka` directory and open the **bin** folder.

2- find the `kafka-topics.sh` file.

3- open it in notepad or any text editor application.

4- paste the following text in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.TopicCommand "$@"
```

finally save and close the text editor.
Done.